# How to enable hover in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have here code made in ReactJS.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Sidebar extends Component {
  state = {
    hovered: false
  };

  onMouseOver = e => {
    this.setState({ hovered: true });
  };

  render() {
    const { hovered } = this.state;
    if (hovered) {
      return (
        <div
          className="flex-container justify-content-end"
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            textDecoration: "none",
            listStyleType: "none"
          }}
          onMouseOver={this.onMouseOver}
        >
          <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
            <ul className="nav flex-column nav-pills">
              <li
                className="nav-item"
                style={{ padding: "0.5em", backgroundColor: "#809fff" }}
              >
                {" "}
                <a
                  href="prva_divizija.html"
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: "#809fff",
                    borderRadius: "15px",
                    color: "white"
                  }}
                  className="nav-link"
                  onMouseOver={this.onMouseOver}
                >
                  PRVA DIVIZIJA
                </a>
              </li>
              <li
                className="nav-item"
                style={{
                  padding: "0.5em"
                }}
              >
                {" "}
                <a
                  href="druga_divizija.html"
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: "#809fff",
                    borderRadius: "15px",
                    color: "white"
                  }}
                  className="nav-link"
                  onMouseOver={this.onMouseOver}
                >
                  DRUGA DIVIZIJA
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item" style={{ padding: "0.5em" }}>
                <a
                  href="treca_divizija.html"
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: "#809fff",
                    borderRadius: "15px",
                    color: "white"
                  }}
                  className="nav-link"
                  onMouseOver={this.onMouseOver}
                >
                  TRECA DIVIZIJA
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item" style={{ padding: "0.5em" }}>
                <a
                  href="cetvrta_divizija.html"
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: "#809fff",
                    borderRadius: "15px",
                    color: "white"
                  }}
                  className="nav-link"
                  onMouseOver={this.onMouseOver}
                >
                  CETVRTA DIVIZIJA
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item" style={{ padding: "0.5em" }}>
                <a
                  href="peta_divizija.html"
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: "#809fff",
                    borderRadius: "15px",
                    color: "white"
                  }}
                  className="nav-link"
                  onMouseOver={this.onMouseOver}
                >
                  PETA DIVIZIJA
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item" style={{ padding: "0.5em" }}>
                <a
                  href="divizija_tuzla.html"
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: "#809fff",
                    borderRadius: "15px",
                    color: "white"
                  }}
                  className="nav-link"
                  onMouseOver={this.onMouseOver}
                >
                  DIVIZIJA TUZLA
                </a>
              </li>

              <li className="nav-item" style={{ padding: "0.5em" }}>
                <a
                  href="divizija_sarajevo.html"
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: "#ff6666",
                    borderRadius: "15px",
                    color: "white"
                  }}
                  className="nav-link"
                  onMouseOver={this.onMouseOver}
                >
                  DIVIZIJA SARAJEVO
                </a>
              </li>

              <li
                className="nav-item"
                style={{
                  padding: "0.5em"
                }}
              >
                <a
                  href="divizija_bugojno.html"
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: "#ff6666",
                    borderRadius: "15px",
                    color: "white"
                  }}
                  className="nav-link"
                  onMouseOver={this.onMouseOver}
                >
                  DIVIZIJA BUGOJNO
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

https://pastebin.com/zYQ4rFxE

The code is suppose to hover when I go over with mouse on the labels. But it doesn't work for some reason. Can I ask for guidance for this solution? I don't ask for finished solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you Hover in ReactJS? - onMouseLeave not registered during fast hover over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29981236/how-do-you-hover-in-reactjs-onmouseleave-not-registered-during-fast-hover-ove)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, react does not have a `hovered` state for a element (like CSS does). However you can use the `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` events to determine if your event is being hovered over and update the state accordingly

See this answer for an example implementation: [react show button on mouse enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35714535/react-show-button-on-mouse-enter#35714597)